# rock paper scissors flow control

Tags: python, flow-control

In the following program for rock paper scissors something is wrong with my loop.  Using the input for set length, the game is played N times for each set.
For cases in which results are player 2, computer 0; player 0, computer 2; player 2, computer 5; player 0, computer 4; an extra game is added to the set.  I have changed the function many times and can't figure out what is wrong.

```
def rpsls_play():
    print("Welcome to the Rock-Scissors-Paper-Lizard-Spock game!")
    player_sets=0
    N=int(input("Select set length: "))
    times=0
    player_wins=0
    computer_wins=0
    while times < N:
        times +=1
        print("Now beginning game", times)
        if rpsls_game()==1:
            player_wins +=1
        else:
            computer_wins +=1
        print("Set score: Player", str(player_wins)+", Computer", str(computer_wins))
    else:
        pass

    if player_wins==computer_wins:
        while abs(player_wins-computer_wins)<2:         
            times +=1
            print("Now beginning game", times)
            if rpsls_game()==1:
                player_wins +=1
            else:
                computer_wins +=1
            print("Set score: Player", str(player_wins)+", Computer", str(computer_wins))
    else:
        pass

    if player_wins>computer_wins:
        print("Congratulations! You have won in", times, "games.")
        player_sets +=1
    elif computer_wins>player_wins:
        print("Too bad! You have lost in", times, "games.")

    pass
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I can't check your code because there is no function `rpsls_game()`.

You didn't say what wrong in your game - what do you get and what do you expect ?

I can only guessing that you have problem with line

```
if player_wins==computer_wins:
```

Extra game is added after N games only if `player_wins == computer_wins`.

You don't need that line.

Comment: I needed that line because if there is a tie they must play until one is winning by two- the problem is that for some reason games are being added when there is no tie

Comment: English is not my native language and I thought you need extra games not only if `player_wins==computer_wins` but also if `abs(player_wins-computer_wins)<2`. I make `rpsls_game()` with `random` to test your code (python 2.x, 3.x) and I don't see problem. It works for me. It adds extra games only if `player_wins==computer_wins`

Comment: Maybe you make modification in one file but accidentally you run different file with old code.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i'll make sure I'm using the right file

Answer (score 1):

Couple code design things that will help improve the code before I get to the answer:

1. You can remove those `else: pass` lines.
2. You can remove that final `pass` statement.

You need to change it to:

```
if player_wins == computer_wins:         
    times +=1
    print("Now beginning tie-breaker game. game", times)
    if rpsls_game()==1:
        player_wins +=1
    else:
        computer_wins +=1
    print("Set score: Player", str(player_wins)+", Computer", str(computer_wins))
```